# Get value from key in non-named nested dictionary within array using python

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve a value from a nested dictionary inside an array with python but I get an error I don't understand. This is the array:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "11-02-2021",
        "Open": 0.07284431,
        "High": 0.0743014,
        "Low": 0.06829016,
        "Close": 0.06967585,
        "Volume": 3818556738.8,
        "Market Cap": 8941609529.45
    },
    {
        "Date": "10-02-2021",
        "Open": 0.07011055,
        "High": 0.08109109,
        "Low": 0.06852545,
        "Close": 0.07289631,
        "Volume": 6785088422.26,
        "Market Cap": 9353895799.46
    }
]
```

This is how I am trying to get the Close value:

```
coin_data = scraper.get_data("json")

today_close_price = coin_data[0]['Close']
yesterday_close_price = coin_data[1]['Close']
```

The error that I get is:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However without the nested dictionary being named I can't use a string, and I would like to grab the value using the key string.

Comment: Include a [example]. Don't call external methods, just hard code the obtained data into the code. (general method to create a [example] taken from [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405052/5267751))

Comment: By the way, post the full traceback.

Comment: Could it be the case that `coin_data = scraper.get_data("json")` contains something other than your provided nested structure? Have you provided your structure by printing `print(coin_data)`? I think it contains string, not structure, do this `print(type(coin_data))`.

Comment: doesn't get_data parse the data into bytestring. If you want them in json, can't you give get_json()

Comment: @Arty yes I have provided the data using ```print(coin_data)```.

Comment: can you do a `type(coin_data)`

Comment: or give `get_data(as_text=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `coin_data` is of type `str`, it is not a structure but string with structure inside. Please do `print(type(coin_data))` in your current code, it should probably output `str`.

Do this to fix your issue (use `json.loads()`):

```
import json

coin_data = scraper.get_data("json")

coin_data = json.loads(coin_data)

today_close_price = coin_data[0]['Close']
yesterday_close_price = coin_data[1]['Close']
```